# Instance attributes in a subclass of Chem.Atom in rdkit cannot be accessed

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, rdkit

I defined a subclass of `Atom` in `rdkit.Chem`. I also defined an instance attribute in it but I could not get that instance from `RWMol` object in rdkit.

Below there is a sample code for my problem:

```
from rdkit import Chem

class MyAtom(Chem.Atom):

    def __init__(self, symbol, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(symbol, **kwargs)
        self.my_attribute = 0

    def get_my_attribute(self):
        return self.my_attribute

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rw_mol = Chem.RWMol()

    # I created MyAtom class object then added to RWMol. But I couldn't get it again.
    my_atom = MyAtom('C')
    my_atom.my_attribute = 3

    rw_mol.AddAtom(my_atom)
    atom_in_mol = rw_mol.GetAtoms()[0]

    # I can access my_atom new defined attributes.
    print(my_atom.get_my_attribute())

    # below two line gives error: AttributeError: 'Atom' object has no attribute 'get_my_attribute'
    print(atom_in_mol.get_my_attribute())
    print(atom_in_mol.my_attribute)

    # type(atom1): <class '__main__.MyAtom'>
    # type(atom_in_mol): <class 'rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Atom'>
    # Why below atom types are different? Thanks to polymorphism, that two object types must be same.
```

Normally this code must run but it gives error due to last line because `atom_in_mol object` type is `Chem.Atom`. But should it be `MyAtom`? I also cannot access `my_attribute` directly.

rdkit Python library is a wrapper of C++. So is the problem this? Cannot I use inheritance for this library?

Note: I researched rdkit documentation and there is a `SetProp` method for saving values in atoms. It uses dictionary to save values. It runs fine but it is too slow for my project. I want to use instance attributes to save my extra values. Is there any solution for that inheritance problem, or faster different solution?

Answer (score 1):

Python RDKit library is a C++ wrapper, so sometimes it does not follows the conventional Python object handling.

To go deeper, you will have to dig through the source code:

```
rw_mol.AddAtom(my_atom)
```

Above will execute `AddAtom` method in [`rdkit/Code/GraphMol/Wrap/Mol.cpp`](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/blob/8bed437c5f00e974e60fe6d6a67b8a1096854e5d/Code/GraphMol/Wrap/Mol.cpp#L183), which, in turn, calls `addAtom` method in [`rdkit/Code/GraphMol/RWMol.h`](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/blob/fa27a5e40a211b8301f907422d273c2fb84cc342/Code/GraphMol/RWMol.h#L81), which then calls `addAtom` method in [`rdkit/Code/GraphMol/ROMol.cpp`](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/blob/fa27a5e40a211b8301f907422d273c2fb84cc342/Code/GraphMol/ROMol.cpp#L334) with default argument of `updateLabel = true` and `takeOwnership = false`.

The `takeOwnership = false` condition makes the argument atom to be duplicated,

```
// rdkit/Code/GraphMol/ROMol.cpp
if (!takeOwnership)
  atom_p = atom_pin->copy();
else
  atom_p = atom_pin;
```

Finally, if you look into what `copy` method do in [rdkit/Code/GraphMol/Atom.cpp](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/blob/8bed437c5f00e974e60fe6d6a67b8a1096854e5d/Code/GraphMol/Atom.cpp#L92)

```
Atom *Atom::copy() const {
  auto *res = new Atom(*this);
  return res;
}
```

So, it reinstantiate Atom class and returns it.

Comment: I understand. Why developers do not add that takeownership parameters to python code?

Comment: I'm not sure, you can easily add a new method and recompile RDKit and see if that conserve your object.

Comment: I examined that method and I do not think so it works. Because if it works, developers already have been added takeownership to python code.